# pyspark streaming how to set ConnectionPool

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a task, I want read data from kafka and use spark spark streaming to process it, and I want send data to Hbase.

In the spark official document, I found:

```
def sendPartition(iter):
    # ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    for record in iter:
        connection.send(record)
    # return to the pool for future reuse
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)

dstream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(sendPartition))
```

But I coudln't find any clue to set up ConnectionPool to Hbase using pyspark.

I also don't understand how streaming is working?
In the code there is `foreachPartition`, I want to be clear those partitions is on the same spark container or not?

Dose all variables in the closure is reset for all each rdd's each partitions ?

Is there way I can set variable at the worker level?

Dose the `globals()` is the worker level ?　Or it is the cluster level?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use thrift to interact with Hbase from pyspark

here is the some code reference

http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/04/22/connect-hbase-with-python-and-thrift/

regarding the parallelization just call your method that will post to Habse inside either foreach or in foreachPartition (which gets executed in distributed manner on all the executors) just make sure you have a dedicated connection for each task/core of your application.

Comment: I know how to interact with Hbase, my question is how to set up a handle through all Rdds in the steaming.